# How can i output just the directory paths when using get-childitem to search for files?

Tags: powershell

I want to output just the directory paths to a text file of where the ps1 files are, how can i do this as in the command above it outputs more info than i need. I just need the directory names where the files are

```
Get-ChildItem -path C:\repos -filter *.ps1 -file -ErrorAction silentlycontinue -recurse  | Out-File C:\repos\psfiles.txt -Encoding ASCII
```

Comment: You simply select the properties you want to output .... ‍♂️ `Get-ChildItem -path C:\repos -filter *.ps1 -file -ErrorAction silentlycontinue -recurse | Select-Object -Property Directory  | Out-File C:\repos\psfiles.txt -Encoding ASCII`

Comment: that worked great

Comment: @Olaf -- if you put this in as an answer, that will be helpful to future visitors.  And the OP can accept it as an answer.